# c++ read in multiple lines, varied delimiters

Tags: c++, stringstream

The input file is structured like:

```
First Last,33,Male,city
score1,15/30
score2, 20/20

First Last,43,Female,city
score1,20/20
score2,18/20
```

with an unknown number of records, each separated by a blank line.  Each record becomes an object to be stored in a dynamic array object (which is confusing in its own right).

I can place the first line into variables, but the remaining lines are lost in the ether.  Although it produces the proper number of records (in this case, it would be 2), each record is filled with the first line's data and no scores.

I just have no ideas about how to read it in properly, and still don't know how to deal with that blank line in between each record.  This was for a previous homework for which I cannot get a straight answer out of anybody, and would love to know, since reading in from files seems to be all the rage...

Here is what I have:

```
std::ifstream read_data(data_file);
std::string line;

while(std::getline(read_data, line))
{
     std::stringstream ss(line);
     char detectNewline;

     getline(ss, tempName, ',');
     getline(ss, tempAgeString, ',');
     tempAge = std::atoi(tempAgeString.c_str());
     getline(ss, tempGender, ',');
     getline(ss, tempCity, '\n';

           for(int i=0; i < 2; i++)  // I am not married to this idea, seems efficient
           {
                getline(ss, tempScore, ',');
                getline(ss, pointsEarnedHolder, '/');
                tempPointsEarned += std::atof(pointsEarnedHolder.c_str());
                getline(ss, totalPointsHolder, '\n');
                tempTotalPoints += std::atof(totalPointsHolder.c_str());
           }

           // variable manipulation

           ClassName object(proper vars);
           previouslyDeclaredDynamicArrayObject(object);

           detectNewline = read_data.peek();
           if(detectNewline == '\n')
           {
              std::cin.ignore();
           }

} //while
```

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: You need to use a basic [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) that is responsible for controlling generating output. Your basic states are **start of record**, **score data**, and **end of record**. You can then walk across and feed each line to the parsing state machine, which will build up records as it goes. At each state you have an individual sub-parser that can extract the relevant data for that line.

Comment: Another approach is to read in the whole file as a single string, and then use a RegEx to extract the individual record matches (in this case your pattern is any amount of text between an empty-line or a start/end of file). You can then pass these record blobs to a simple constructor for your record class that knows how to parse a string that contains a single record.

Comment: Instead of trying to vary delimiters while reading input, you should read in whole lines, according the structure put this into an `std::istringstream` parse the items using the primary delimiter `','` , and break up the score parts (using delimiter `'/'`) separately. Using `std::regex` as @aruisdante mentioned is also a good idea.

Comment: Mm, that would work as well. Basically, think about trying to segment the data into the largest possible macro-block (a record), then passing that macro-block into a function that will split that macro-block into smaller macro-blocks (header lines and score lines), which then passes that data into functions that know how to parse the individual line types. Don't try to do it all in one massive function of doom. In fact, it's often easiest to work backwards. Build the function that given a header line produces the correct data structure. Then one that parses a score line. And so on upwards.

Comment: `std::getline` just reads the first line. When you go into your `i` loop you try to extract the contents of lines 2 and 3 from line 1, which obviously fails. You have to `getline` from the actual file to get line 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I will touch on a way to read the information efficiently.

First you can getline the first line and parse the information like you have. Then you will parse the information provided in the scores until `getline` hits a blank line. Then once this happens you will add the object into the array, and get the starting information for the next object and then repeat the process.

The code would look similar to this (pretty pseudo-y):

> ```
> std::getline(read_data, line);
> while( !read_data.eof() ) {
>    std::stringstream ss(line);
>
>    getline(ss, tempName, ',');
>    getline(ss, tempAgeString, ',');
>    tempAge = std::atoi(tempAgeString.c_str());
>    getline(ss, tempGender, ',');
>    getline(ss, tempCity, '\n';
>    std::getline( read_data, line )
>    while( line != "\n" ) {
>         getline(ss, tempScore, ',');
>         getline(ss, pointsEarnedHolder, '/');
>         tempPointsEarned += std::atof(pointsEarnedHolder.c_str());
>         getline(ss, totalPointsHolder, '\n');
>         tempTotalPoints += std::atof(totalPointsHolder.c_str());
>         std::getline( read_data, line )
>    }
>
>          // variable manipulation
>
>          ClassName object(proper vars);
>          previouslyDeclaredDynamicArrayObject(object);
>          std::getline(read_data, line);
>
>  } //while
> ```

This is assuming that you are properly extracting the information from the lines.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to delimit upon those characters is to classify them as whitespace through the `std::ctype<>` facet of the streams locale. Then you can simply use the extractor `operator>>()` instead of parsing through the unformatted functions.

Here's an example of how to set the facet:

```c++
struct ctype : std::ctype<char>
{
    static mask* make_table()
    {
        const mask* table = classic_table();
        static std::vector<mask> v(table, table + table_size);
        v[' '] |= space;
        v[','] |= space;
        v['/'] |= space;
        return &v[0];
    }

    ctype() : std::ctype<char>(make_table()) { }
};
```

You can then make a convience function to install it into the stream's locale:

```c++
std::istream& custom_ctype(std::istream& is)
{
    is.imbue(std::locale(is.getloc(), new ctype));
    return *is;
}

// ...
file >> custom_ctype;
```

After that it becomes simple to extract characters from the file into variables. Just think of the characters that you want to ignore as if they were the space character or the newline character, because that's exactly what we've done here.